# Why does only the procedural style of mysqli_query require a $link argument?

Tags: php, mysqli

Referencing: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

```
mysqli::query ( string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )

 link
 Procedural style only: A link identifier returned by mysqli_connect() or mysqli_init()
```

So, the question is why does only the procedural style of mysqli_query require a $link argument?

Comment: Because that's how the library was built?

Comment: Because when using `$mysqli->query()` the `$mysqli` object already has the "link" from when instantiated the object like this `$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`

Comment: Because classes carry their state, as discussed in OOP 101.

Comment: @AbraCadaver:  that makes sense, but (although it is very poor style), it is technically legal to mix procedural and object oriented methods in mysqli, so the link could be initiated with `$link = mysqli_connect( 'host', 'username', 'password', 'database')`?  I think this might be a case of RTFM, where I read through the mysqli documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli` is a class. Whether you instantiate it using `new mysqli()` or `mysqli_connect()` the result is an object of `mysqli` class.

The procedural style functions are just thin wrappers for the class methods, so as to enable quicker migration from `mysql_*` API. In hindsight, this was probably not such a smart idea. You can imagine these functions more or less like this:

```
function mysqli_query(mysqli $link, string $query, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT) {
    return $link->query($query, $resultmode);
}
```

Internally they trigger the same methods on the provided object, but instead of calling methods you call a function and pass the object as the first argument.